# Setting minimum and maximum values for DxMaskedInput tag in Blazor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Hello fellow Blazor developers, I am seeking help with setting minimum and maximum values for DxMaskedInput tag in Blazor. I am currently using the following code:

```
<DxMaskedInput @bind-Value="@_dealSize"
               CssClass="cw-320"
               Mask="N2"
/>
```

I want to set the minimum and maximum values for _dealSize, but I am encountering an error when trying to use the following code example that uses the ValueChanged event:

```
<DxMaskedInput Value="Value"
            ValueChanged="@((int newValue) => OnValueChanged(newValue))"
            Mask="@NumericMask.Currency">
</DxMaskedInput>
<DxButton Enabled="@IsEnabled">Update Value</DxButton>

@code {
    int Value = 0;
    bool IsEnabled = false;

    void OnValueChanged(int newValue)
    {
        Value = newValue;
        if (newValue != 0)
            IsEnabled = true;
        else IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

The error I am encountering is:

```
{"EventId":111,"LogLevel":"Error","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost",
"Message":"Unhandled exception in circuit \u0027WRZkSd3ggsKGlKKJZfwrV9sDpWQEmJjBFDRYdMjbsoc\u0027.",
"Exception":
"System.InvalidOperationException: 
DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.Editors.Models.MaskedInputModel requires a value for the \u0027ValueExpression\u0027 property. 
It is specified automatically when you use two-way binding(\u0027bind-Value\u0027).    at 
DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.Editors.Models.MaskedInputModel\u00601.CheckValueExpression()    at 
DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.Editors.Models.DataEditorModel\u00601.CreateFieldIdentifier()    at 
DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.Editors.Models.DataEditorModel\u00601.OnValidationStateChanged()    at 
DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.Editors.Models.DataEditorModel\u00601.ApplyParameterChanges()    at 
DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.ParameterTracker.EndUpdate()    at 
DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.Editors.Models.DataEditorModel\u00601.EndUpdate()    at 
DevExpress.Blazor.Base.DxDataEditor\u00601.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)",
"State":{"Message":"Unhandled exception in circuit \u0027WRZkSd3ggsKGlKKJZfwrV9sDpWQEmJjBFDRYdMjbsoc\u0027.",
"CircuitId":"WRZkSd3ggsKGlKKJZfwrV9sDpWQEmJjBFDRYdMjbsoc",
"{OriginalFormat}":"Unhandled exception in circuit \u0027{CircuitId}\u0027."}}
```

If anyone has experience with this, I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you in advance!

I want to set min and max value of DxMaskedInput tag in Blazor

Answer (score 0):

You either set the `ValueExpression` parameter manually:

```
<DxMaskedInput Value="Value"
               ValueChanged="@((int newValue) => OnValueChanged(newValue))"
               ValueExpression="@(() => Value)"
               Mask="@NumericMask.Currency">
</DxMaskedInput>
<DxButton Enabled="@IsEnabled">Update Value</DxButton>

@code {
    int Value = 0;
    bool IsEnabled = false;

    void OnValueChanged(int newValue)
    {
        Value = newValue;
        if (newValue != 0)
            IsEnabled = true;
        else IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Or use two-way binding with the `@bind-Value` syntax and change `IsEnabled` to calculated property:

```
<DxMaskedInput @bind-Value="Value"
               Mask="@NumericMask.Currency">
</DxMaskedInput>
<DxButton Enabled="@IsEnabled">Update Value</DxButton>

@code {
    int Value = 0;
    bool IsEnabled => Value != 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

To add min and max value you can either use [`DxSpinEdit`](https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/SpinEdit#Mask) component which also has mask support and you can specify the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` parameters.

Or you can manually check for min and max inside `OnValueChanged`:

```
<DxMaskedInput Value="Value"
               ValueChanged="@((int newValue) => OnValueChanged(newValue))"
               ValueExpression="@(() => Value)"
               Mask="@NumericMask.Currency">
</DxMaskedInput>

@code {
    int Value = 0;
    const int MaxValue = 100;
    const int MinValue = -100;

    void OnValueChanged(int newValue)
    {
        if (newValue > MaxValue)
        {
            Value = MaxValue;
        }
        else if (newValue < MinValue)
        {
            Value = MinValue;
        }
        else
        {
            Value = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right. But Could you please tell me about how to set max and min value in DxMaskedInput tag? Best Regards.

Comment: Maybe you should use the [DxSpinEdit](https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/SpinEdit#Mask) component. It has [`MinValue` and `MaxValue`](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxSpinEdit-1.MaxValue) parameters. Otherwise you have to manually check the `newValue` inside `OnValueChanged` and set the `Value` field accordingly. I will update my answer with example.